# How can I run a .clj Clojure file I created?

Tags: command-line, clojure

I wrote a small "hello world" program on Linux to get started with the language.

Now I'd like to run it and see what it outputs.

How can I run this code?
What command should I run?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

FWIW, I'm interpreting the question here as specifically asking how to run a single file, like a script, versus as a part of a compiled project.
Obviously though, there's a relationship between how and why you would want to run a single file, and how you would want to build a full project, so I weigh that in some as well.

## Best choice: the `clj` tooling

Docs are here:

https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli

This is an official part of the Clojure project, which by itself is a pretty good reason to go this route. However, it has a couple of advantages over the other solutions here:

- cleaner dependency resolution model, via `deps.edn`
- also resolve dependencies via git references!
- `~/.clojure/deps.edn` seems to do a better job of cleanly providing reusable functionality via its aliass than `~/.lein/profiles.clj`
- if you need to load your code in a repl, `clj` won't choke on a borked src file, like `lein repl` does

Simply

`clj your-code-file.clj`

Or if you have dependencies

`clj -Sdeps '{:deps {clj-time {:mvn/version "0.14.2"}}}' -M your-code-file.clj`

Works well as a shebang in scripts as well!

```
#!clj -Sdeps '{:deps {clj-time {:mvn/version "0.14.2"}}} -M
(ns my-crazy-script!
  (:require ...))
...
```

I recommend installing with [homebrew](https://brew.sh), which now works on both Mac and Linux. If you're on Windows I'd recommend using the WSL+brew.

The one advantage I see of `lein` (see below) tooling over `clj` generally is that `lein` handles a little more of the process of *building* and *packaging* your code base, when you get to that point.
However, there are other ways of handing that (see [pack](https://github.com/juxt/pack), [uberdeps](https://github.com/tonsky/uberdeps) or cambada), and the advantages of `clj` mentioned above outweigh IMHO.

## Babashka

If you are trying to run a single file, as apposed to an entire project, there's a good chance your in "scripting territory".
Unfortunately, the JVM takes a while to boot up, as does Clojure itself.
Via the magic of GraalVM and the [SCI](https://github.com/borkdude/sci), [Babashka](https://babashka.org/) is able to support most of the Clojure language with blazing fast startup times.
It also comes with quite a few "batteries included" for typical scripting tasks, making it a perfect complement to `clj` when you want fast-executing, short lived processes.

Once you install it you can simply `bb you-code-file.clj`, or use `#!bb` in your shebang.
See the docs for more usage instructions:

https://babashka.org/

## With `lein` & `lein-exec`

If you prefer `lein` tooling, or have a `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file handy already and don't want to invest in learning `clj`/`deps.edn`, you can consider looking at [`lein-exec`](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec).

If you already have a `project.clj` set up with dependencies, you can of course run `lein run -m <yer-namespace>[/<yer-main-fn>]`.

As mentioned above, the one advantage of `lein` over `clj` is that it is a complete build tool, and can make jars/uberjars for you with `lein jar` or `lein uberjar`, do deploys and such.

## For ClojureScript

I'd recommend http://planck-repl.org/. It now supports (bootstrapped) quick launching of ClojureScript scripts without having to fire up the JVM or Clojure.
Like babashka, this makes it great for scripting.
However, I find babashka both more powerful and more natural for scripting, so I'd start there unless you have a particular reason for wanting to use Cljs (more familiarity with JS/node, need of certain cljs libraries, etc).

For more substantial projects (beyond scripting), you may want to look at Shadlow-CLJS, for its ease of incorporating vanilla JS projects.
And FWIW, Shadow nicely integrates with both deps and lein, and has it's own built in hode code reloading, like figwheel.

## With `java`

You can, of course, as has been suggested in another answer, use

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main file.clj
```

But you don't see that in the wild too often, because it's a pain to have to find the path to your `clojure.jar` and manually composing classpaths for dependencies sucks.
But, you know, to each their own.

Comment: Thank you! `sudo apt-get install clojure` and then `clojure hello.clj`

Comment: lein exec is the way to go.

Comment: @qed - Agreed; that's the way I typically go.

Comment: If you are looking for it, I wrote a quick and dirty [blog](https://quazirfan.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/installing-exec-plugin-in-leiningen-project/) post about how to install the exec plugin.

Comment: @qed Why is `lein exec` "the way to go"? Why not use `clojure` ?

Comment: @AlexanderPresber Because `lein` gives you a way to declare dependencies, while `clojure` does not.

Comment: Note: I've updated the answer here to reflect that we now have the "official" `clj`/`clojure` CLI tools available. The `clojure` tooling here is not to be confused with the `clojure` I mentioned in an earlier version of this, which was put up on Ubuntu by who knows. Just for context for those of you reading comments above.

Comment: Another option for lein which I prefer over `lein-exec` is `inlein` https://github.com/hypirion/inlein

Comment: I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: <FILE>.clj (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Hi @SnehaaGanesan. A little hard to know what might be going on here without more details. Do you want to post your issue as a separate question?

Comment: Update : I was executing it from the wrong directory. Had to be in the root of the class path for a successful execution. Thank you @metasoarous for the suggestion.

Comment: @metasoarous Your shebang answer did not work for me.  I think `-deps` should be `-Sdeps`, the single-quote around the deps is never balanced, and newer `clj` versions will complain about "Implicit use of clojure.main" without the `-M` flag.

I added an answer to cover the shebang-deps case for Linux and Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583270/2016618

Answer (score 59):

You can run script with following command:

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main file.clj
```

but it's better to use [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen), especially when you'll start to add dependencies to your project. lein provides number of commands to run your code (with all necessary dependencies), pack code into archive with `lein jar`, or create complete, independent archives with `lein uberjar` that you can run with:

```
java -jar your_app.jar
```

command

P.S. You can read how to use `lein` in [following article](http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureLein.html) - it describes base tasks & configurations

Comment: Maybe add that he has to make a project first with lein new and make the clj file part of the project, for example core.clj

Comment: Yes, it's creating project could be useful... I added link to my article on how to work with lein

Comment: Alex, I have been trying this but it just shows an empty line; I have a println in the file but it never prints it; is there any thing am missing?
java -cp clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main ..\hey.clj

Comment: Works fine for me... Do you have println in the top-level of the source code, or inside the function? If the later, then the function is compiled, but never run... Following works for me without any problem: `echo '(println "test")' > 1.clj` ; `java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main 1.clj`

Comment: I keep getting `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: <FILENAME>.clj (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 16):

Once you've installed lein and the [lein-exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) plugin, running the .clj file you've created is as simple as

```
lein exec hello.clj
```

In case you're passing command line arguments like

```
lein exec hello.clj arg1 arg2 arg3
```

you can access them in the 'foo' function in your hello.clj like

```
(foo *command-line-args*)
```

Answer (score 9):

For a single clj file you can add,

```
#!/usr/bin/env java -cp /path/to/clojure-1.2.0.jar clojure.main
```

to the top of the file and make it executable or you can use leiningen which is a clojure build tool it will create a single jar that has everything packed, then you can just do,

```
java -jar cool_app.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to execute a single file, how about piping it to the repl like:

`cat $PATH_TO_FILE | lein repl`

Answer (score 2):

For running a single file through command line use the following commands:

```
clj -m (NameSpace name)
```

ex: `clj -m Sample`

Or if you want to run through repl:

```
(load-file filelocation)
```

ex:

```
 (load-file "Sample.clj")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Drip](https://github.com/flatland/drip) is probably now the best answer to this question (see [Drip's wiki](https://github.com/flatland/drip/wiki/Clojure) for details on using Drip with Clojure).

Cake was incorporated into Leiningen and has since been superseded as the most stable implementation of Clojure automation by Drip - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906276/whats-the-difference-between-cake-and-leiningen) to a similar question here.

Answer (score 1):

I really like writing small .clj scripts, but sometimes those scripts have dependencies that need to be installed.  Since none of the other answers cover that case, I provide an example here.  This example is a single-file script that requires the `permutations` function from the [`math.combinatorics`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics) library.

---

### Cumbersome Mac-only solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env clj -Sdeps {:deps,{org.clojure/math.combinatorics,{:mvn/version,"0.1.6"}}} -M
; Explanation for the shebang:
;   -Sdeps  Specify deps in EDN format
;   ,       Clojure interprets commas as whitespace. Without the commas, the EDN is
;           broken up into multiple arguments and the command fails. On the
;           command line you can use single quotes around the EDN string, but
;           Mac shebangs don't support quoting around arguments.
;   -M      Run the program as a "main" function

(ns foo
  (:use [clojure.math.combinatorics :only (permutations)]))

(dorun (map #(println (apply str %)) (permutations "abcde")))
```

### Linux-only solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S clj -Sdeps '{:deps {org.clojure/math.combinatorics {:mvn/version "0.1.6"}}}' -M
; Explanation for the shebang:
;   env -S  Allow multiple arguments to be passed to the following command
;   -Sdeps  Specify deps in EDN format
;   -M      Run the program as a "main" function

(ns foo
  (:use [clojure.math.combinatorics :only (permutations)]))

(dorun (map #(println (apply str %)) (permutations "abcde")))
```

### Portable solution (Linux and Mac)

See [the planck docs](https://github.com/planck-repl/planck/blob/5b03bf6a5131fed8eef3ad63c69dadf8ada57182/doc/dependencies.md#shebang-deps) for an explanation.  It's very clever!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
"exec" "clj" "-Sdeps" "{:deps {org.clojure/math.combinatorics {:mvn/version \"0.1.6\"}}}" "-M" "$0" "$@"

(ns foo
  (:use [clojure.math.combinatorics :only (permutations)]))

(dorun (map #(println (apply str %)) (permutations "abcde")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Install clojure from the below official link according to your OS

https://clojure.org/guides/install_clojure

Now we can easily execute files by below command **tested on mac only**. Other complicated steps aren't required now I think.

write a sample print statement in your file `hello-world.clj`

```
(println "Hello world")
```

Run your program with the below command in terminal

```
clj -M hello-world.clj
```

It will output

```
Hello world
```

Tested on Clojure `Version: 1.11.1.1200`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in running a specific clojure script file out of a clojure project using `lein`. Then I found a shortcut, thought of sharing the same.

In `project.clj` file, you can toggle the clojure script file name ( which has main method of course). Following is the statement for this.

`:main ^:skip-aot conv.newconv` `; here conv is namespace and newconv is the file name` .

***Note:*** I am new to clojure and I am not sure why '^:skip-aot` is used, I have not checked that.

***Note:*** This methodology, does not require any plugin to be installed nor any jar file need to be generated. This only requires to change a name in project file.

**Assumption:** Your clojure project has multiple clojure files, each having main method. I am assuming this is created for testing purpose only. My solution will work for this specific scenario.