# Geany as CommonLisp IDE

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, indentation, geany

Has anyone experiences with setting up Geany as IDE for commonlisp? I have sbcl installed, this is the output of `whereis sbcl`:

```
sbcl: /usr/bin/sbcl /usr/lib/sbcl /etc/sbcl.rc /usr/share/man/man1/sbcl.1.gz
```

However when i run a program with F5 in Geany i get this in the terminal seeming it searches for clisp:

```
/tmp/geany_run_script_9ZR2LY.sh: 7: /tmp/geany_run_script_9ZR2LY.sh: clisp: not found
```

More over the indentation is also deactivated when in the lisp mode.
Can anyone help?

I am using Ubuntu-studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I installed Geany, typed `(print "Hi")`, saved the file and tried to execute it. It worked, but that's because I happen to have CLisp installed.

Under the Build menu, you have a "Set build commands" item which allows you to change the executable. You should type:

```
sbcl --script "%f"
```

However, now you can only run a script and you lose all the *productive* and *fun* interactive part of working with a dynamic programming environment like Common Lisp. 
See related questions and answers for getting started with Emacs+slime:

- [Setting up a working Common Lisp environment for the aspiring Lisp newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101487/setting-up-a-working-common-lisp-environment-for-the-aspiring-lisp-newbie)
- [Setting the SLIME in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607716/setting-the-slime-in-emacs)

Comment: @amirteymuri see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656523/how-can-i-run-a-clj-clojure-file-i-created

Answer (score 2):

You may find useful this [CL Plugin for Geany](https://phab.jasom.org/diffusion/GL/repository/master/) was released. It is known to work with SBCL. It is still alpha though. Although it requires Emacs to be installed it is only used as batch processing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Geany plugin at https://github.com/tgutu/geanylispedit

It lets you interact with a Lisp REPL started inside Geany's terminal, and send S-expressions to it via keyboard shortcuts. This seems to give a decent environment.

**Edit:**

The plugin is quite old and must be compiled manually after installing a few dependencies. You may have to tweak the `Makefile` by hand, on my system I had to add `-I/usr/include/vte-0.0/` to the `geanylispedit.o` target.

The keyboard shortcuts are nice but it still lacks proper auto-indentation, which makes it barely usable.